# EClipse CDT/Juno and linker options --start-group

Tags: linker, eclipse-cdt

I know the -l and -L options for link but I am looking to set the --start-group and --end-group and all my libraries into my C project (Properties) under CDT/Juno but where do I put this option ????
-Xlinker ?

Thanks
Marc

Comment: I think you'll need to use a manually-maintained Makefile to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert this options through "Expert settings: Command line patterns".
To insert the options `-Wl,--start-group` and `-Wl,--end-group` you can edit this field. Follow the steps below:

1. Click in the option GCC C/C++ Linker
2. Edit the field Command line pattern

from

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}
```

to

```
 ${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} $(OBJS) -Wl,--start-group $(USER_OBJS) -Wl,--end-group $(LIBS)
```

Notice that we are open the variable `${INPUTS}` that's equal `INPUT="$(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)"`. Check the result in the makefile generated.

3. Insert your static files in the section GCC C/C++ Linker -> Miscellaneous -> Other objects.

Comment: Just what I needed to get the Intel MKL linked in to my project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue - a quick workaround I used was to make the first entry in my toolchain linker "other objects" list the value "-Wl,--start-group" and the last entry "-Wl,--end-group".