# How to link Intel MKL using Eclipse, --start-group --end-group

Tags: eclipse-cdt, intel-mkl

I'm having trouble linking against Intel MKL using Eclipse CDT.  The advice from [Intel's Link Line Advisor Tool](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-a), per my specific requirements, is to use the Link Line:

```
-Wl,--start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

A more readable form of what I need:

```
--start-group -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core --end-group
```

The problem is the --start-group --end-group syntax is not (AFAIK) an option within Eclipse.  The MKL library has a lot of circular dependencies; this syntax is necessary to avoid having to repeatedly link libraries.  Without this syntax, I have this terrible list of libs:

```
-lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -lmkl_sequential
```

So the question is how to configure Eclipse CDT to link Intel MKL libraries, using the --start-group syntax to prevent circular references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem searching StackOverflow.  [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43830240/4486071) on Eclipse CDT and the --start-group option was almost exactly the solution.  A slight modification was required; putting the $(LIBS) variable in the group, not the $(USER_OBS).

So From:

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}
```

To This:

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) -Wl,--start-group $(LIBS) -Wl,--end-group
```

Results in a working Eclipse build.  Command line looks like:

```
g++ -L"Intel MKL 2019.5.281/linux/lib" -shared -o "myLibrary.so"  ./MyObject.o -Wl,--start-group -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -Wl,--end-group
```